# What are the USB plugs for motherboard headers called

Tags: usb, motherboard, computer-building

I have a computer case where the motherboard plug for the front side USB ports has single pin, individual plugs for each wire in the USB cable.  I would like to swap it out for the more common 9 pin plug, but I'm lost as to what those things are called to look them up.

Comment: Do you have a pic you can post? Or perhaps provide the model number of the motherboard? The only thing that comes to mind is “[USB internal header 9-pin cable](https://www.google.com/search?q=USB+internal+header+9-pin+cable&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwj2isaoi47uAhU9cjABHVrRB5kQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=USB+internal+header+9-pin+cable)” but I could be mistaken.

Comment: @Giacomo1968, those are the exact plugs I'm talking about.  I just don't know what to call them to look up in part systems.

Comment: Look at what I searched on “USB internal header 9-pin cable.” Are you searching for parts on a specific site? Let me know and see if I can find them there.